# Why doesn't my passport app authenticate users?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I'm building a passport app that should search through a mysql database for an email and authenticate the user if the password matches. This is my code:

```
const express = require("express")
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { Model, Sequelize, Datatypes } = require("sequelize");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("edit_site", "root", "Ratman4992", {
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "mysql",
    "port": 3306
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 30001

const app = express();

const User = sequelize.define("user", {
    "email": {
        "type": Sequelize.STRING,
        "allowNull": false
    },
    "password": {
        "type": Sequelize.STRING,
        "allowNull": false
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended": true}));

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        "usernameField": "email",
        "passwordField": "password"
    }, 
    (email, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({"where": { "email": email }}, (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                return done(error);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {"message": "Incorrect username."});
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {"message": "Incorrect password."});
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err); 
        }
        console.log(info);
        if (!user) {
            console.log("no user");
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        console.log(user);
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(user);
                return next(err); 
            }
            return res.redirect('/users/' + user.email);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.post("/api/signup", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.create({
        "email": req.body.email,
        "password": req.body.password
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect(307, "/api/login");
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.json(error);
    });
});

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(session({
    "secret": "cats", 
    "resave": false,
    "saveUninitialized": true,
    "cookie": {"secure": false }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("listening to requests on port " + port);
    });
});
```

Posting to /api/signup successfully creates an entry in the database. But when trying to sign in with the same email and password, I only get this message in the console:

`` Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `password`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`email` = 'test@gmail.com' LIMIT 1; ``

And then testing for `req.user` returns `false` when I'm expecting an authenticated user. Why doesn't the user authenticate?

I'm using Express to create the server, MySQL 80 to store the email, password, session id, etc., Sequelize to interface with the database, and PassportJS to authenticate.

Comment: On the /login route, the final (req, res, next) is needed?

Comment: Do you mean I'm supposed to provide something for `req`, `res`, and `next`? Or do you mean `app.post` should be called with `(req, res, next)`? The latter doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Like this? without the last (req, res, next)

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err); 
        }
        console.log(info);
        if (!user) {
            console.log("no user");
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        console.log(user);
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(user);
                return next(err); 
            }
            return res.redirect('/users/' + user.email);
        });
    });
});
```